# <cfcatch> not 'catching' an error

Tags: exception, coldfusion

I've got an image processing CFC to handle uploaded images. In the method, I'm creating an new image of the uploaded file with `ImageNew()` and then resizing it if needed (along with some other validation to make sure it's an image). Here's a snippet of the code:

```
<cftry>
        <cfset ImageScaleToFit(#local.uploadedImage#, 72, "", "highestPerformance")>
        <cfimage action="write" source="#local.uploadedImage#" destination="#local.newThumbName#" overwrite="yes" >
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfset local.response['catcher'] = #cfcatch.Detail#>
            <cfset local.response['success'] = false>
            <cfreturn local.response>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
```

After I upoloaded the code to the production server it began throwing an error because "highestPerformance" isn't an available option for image compression on the production server.

As a backup for `<cftry>` exception handling I have the Application.cfc send me an email of the details while masking the errors from the user in the event the 'try' doesn't cathc the error.

Throughout the CFC the `<cftry>` catches the error and sends it back to my page. where it gets output to the console.

My question is, why does this particular block of code not work with `<cftry>` and the error gets sent directly to the exception handling in my Application.CFC?

Is there some sort of "error threshold" that my built-in exception handling can't handle?

BTW, "highPerformance" works for some reason  even though the documentation at Adobe says "highestPerformance" is an available option...

**EDIT:**

Here's the error I'm getting from the Application.cfc

`Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI`

And the stack trace:

`ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI at coldfusion.image.Image.resizeImageWithJAI(Image.java:1189) at coldfusion.image.Image.resize(Image.java:1119) at coldfusion.image.Image.scaleToFit(Image.java:974) at coldfusion.image.Image.scaleToFit(Image.java:959) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ImageScaleToFit(CFPage.java:6189) at cfspecials2ecfc103515531$funcUPLOADFILEXHR.runFunction(C:\cfc\thecfc.cfc:143) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418) at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471) at cfspecials2ecfc103515531$funcMULTIUPLOAD.runFunction(C:\cfc\thecfc.cfc:32) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418) at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:453) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:320) at coldfusion.filter.ComponentFilter.invoke(ComponentFilter.java:183) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:282) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:138) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doPost(CFCServlet.java:289) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760) at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86) at com.seefusion.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:49) at com.seefusion.SeeFusion.doFilter(SeeFusion.java:1494) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101) at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106) at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42) at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286) at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543) at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203) at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320) at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428) at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266) at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)`

Comment: Can you post the error message received by `Application.cfc`?

Comment: @orangepips: Just added the error message info...

Comment: Looks like @Dave Long may have the right idea. See this Adobe Forum thread: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2296928. Aside from updating ColdFusion, another thing to try is from `onError()` log/email `#exception.stacktrace#` to get files and line numbers of where the exception is occurring.

Comment: @Ofeargall - What is the full error, including the stack trace?

Comment: @Leigh: Added the stack trace. Here's the raw trace: `at cfspecials2ecfc103515531$funcUPLOADFILEXHR.runFunction(C:\websites\anumberhere\path\to\cfc\cfchandling.cfc:143)`

Comment: @Ofeargall - I cannot be certain, but `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions usually mean there is multiple versions of a jar in the class path. a) Are you using anything *other* than the built in image functions and b) do you have createObject() access on this server?

Comment: @Leigh - It turns out the problem is from the method of interpolation I had chosen. For example in the `ImageScaleToFit()` I used "highestPerformance" and that threw the error. When I changed to "highPerformance" there were no errors. I'm still not certain why is makes it past the `<cftry>`... An error is an error... Or maybe not.

Comment: @Ofeargall - No, there are different types of errors. But IF the code works locally, I would be more interested in *why* it fails with an error on the remote host. It is not your typical permissions denied error. It sounds more like a server configuration problem.

Comment: @Leigh, I suspect that the 'reason' for the error is platform contingent. My guess is that hosting.com has their interpolation options in the `ImageScaleToFit()` ratcheted down to a minimum. THe tech wasn't able to tell me which options were available to me, I simply had to run some tests until I found one that was non-offensive to their particular configuration.

Comment: @Ofeargall - I suppose anything is possible on a shared host. But I was not even aware that was possible with ImageScaleToFit. Plus, that really does not jive with the error message you are seeing. The error suggests something is broken, not permissions limited.

Comment: @Leigh, excellent point! Hadn't thought of that. Maybe I can do some arm twisting because there is a noticeable difference in the speed between "highestPerformance" and "highPerformance".

Comment: @Ofeargall - Btw - Do you have createObject(java) access on this server?

Comment: @Leigh, I'm using `ImageNew()` now. I supposed that was the same, am i wrong?

Comment: @Ofeargall - No it is different. It is probably disabled, but try this to verify: `<cfset str = createObject("java", "java.lang.String").init("apple")>
<cfdump var="#str#">`.

Comment: @Leigh, it dumps "apple" to the screen so, that must be a good sign.

Comment: @Ofeargall - Yes. Surprisingly it is not disabled. Out of curiosity, can you tell where `javax.media.jai.JAI` is loaded from?  http://www.bpurcell.org/blog/index.cfm?entry=982&mode=entry

Comment: @Leigh, No luck... `macromedia/jdbc/oracle/OracleDriver.class: [ could not resolve resource]`

Comment: You need to replace `..OracleDriver` with the JAI class. Though it may not be available either.

Comment: Ah, foolish me. Sorry about that. Same result, though... "could not resolve resource". I'm in a CF8 server so I wonder if it's in a different home?

Comment: Well .. the value is not always accessible. Assuming the class name is correct, it could be undefined due to insufficient permissions. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29 But all this was before you spoke with tech. support. Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: To stop the error all together I needed to call a less resource intensive option within the `ImageScaleToFit()` function. I chose "highPerformance" as opposed to "highestPerformance". I think the real solution for the original post was to recognize that `<cftry>` is a great tool, but that there will be some errors that it won't catch and, unfortunately, I don't always get to know what those errors are. Rough answer to swallow for a control freak like me.

Comment: @Ofeargall - Well.. not really a solution ;) Unless explicitly disabled, built in CF functions should work. So tech support should have an explanation for why this one does not. Especially after saying "due to server resources not being available at that moment" .. implying they should now be available. As far as errors, I think orangepips already gave a plausible explanation of what you can and cannot catch ie Exception versus Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ColdFusion 8 make sure that you have all hotfixes and updates applied.  CF 8 had a lot of major issues with image functions and tags, and if Java is causing the error underneath CF might not be able to catch it.  Even if you aren't on CF 8 make sure that everything is updated.

Comment: I am running CF8 with all the hotfixes locally and CF8 on Hosting.com shared.

Comment: If I remember correctly there is something wrong with the image stuff on hosting.com.  I would suggest using ImageCFC, which is what a lot of opensource apps use to work natively with Railo, OpenBD, and other CF servers that don't support image tages and functions http://imagecfc.riaforge.org/

Comment: I understand the limitations of the image functions on certain servers but I just wasn't understanding why the `try/catch` block wasn't capturing the error. Seems like a waste of time to use the exception handling if it isn't going to do anything and just refer to the Application.cfc.

Comment: It sounds more like an internal error that should not be happening, than a limitation. IIRC, type="any" does not catch absolutely *everything*. So certain exotic exceptions may fall through to onError.

Comment: Guess this has to do with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` extending `java.lang.Error` instead of `java.lang.Exception`. Where `Error` is documented as "An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch." http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Comment: I don't know if I should feel good that I've got a "reasonable application" or terrible because I've got a "serious problem" - lol.

Comment: @orangepips - I had forgotten the specifics, but sounds like a very plausible explanation.

Comment: @Ofeargall: more like this type of problem is not one a programmer is expected to be able to write code so the application can recover and move on.

Comment: @All - Tech support reported back that the error was due to server resources not being available at that moment to process the request at the setting "highestPerformance". I just wish that I could identify those potential failures that might slip past my `<cftry>` block and handle them in a more elegant manner.

Comment: There is not much you can about a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Realistically, you cannot recover from it or do anything about it in your code. So displaying a friendly error message is probably as elegant as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

The catch fails because the call to ImageScaleToFit() crashes the JVM. It sounds like your production sever is either missing the Java Advanced Imaging API (javax.media.jai.JAI) or it is not included in the classpath.

Comment: Missing classes usually (though not always) generate a `ClassNotFoundException`. In my experience `NoClassDefFoundError` usually indicates a different problem, like a classloader conflict. But it is not the most informative error. So there can be different causes. http://jroller.com/sjivan/entry/difference_between_classnotfoundexception_and_noclassdeffounderror

Comment: I just ran into this error on my production server, which consistently performs the fn. ImageScaleToFit() successfully. @JhnSctt might be onto something in that the JVM crashes, but it's not necessarily because you're missing anything. In my case, I think the user uploaded a crappy image that crashed the JVM. Not sure why the error is not being caught.