# Uncatchable exception in ColdFusion?

Tags: exception, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I stumbled upon a very weird issue in ColdFusion which might very well be a bug, but I wanted to post it here in case I was missing something.

It seems that `cfindex` is throwing an uncatchable exception when trying to index *invalid files*.

I'm not entirely sure yet what consists of an *invalid file*, but the issue occurs with a valid PDF file, but that doesn't have a PDF extension. Obviously, the problem can easily be fixed by adding a valid extension, but that's not the scope of the question.

```
<cftry>
    <cfindex 
        collection="some_collection"
        action="update"
        key="//someserver/some_file_without_extension">

    After index

    <cfcatch type="any">
        Exception caught
    </cfcatch>

    <cffinally>
        Finally block
    </cffinally>
</cftry>

Completed
```

When running the above code, the only thing that is output is `Finally block`, therefore it's like if there is an exception thrown, but which cannot be caught.

I even tried with `type="java.lang.Exception"`, `type="java.lang.Throwable"` and `type="searchengine"` and nothing works.

The only way I found to detect such exceptions is to check a boolean flag in the `finally` block, but gracefully recovering form those errors is very cumbersome.

Another very weird thing that occurs is that right after the issue is encountered, if I refresh the page in the browser, I'll get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 503.0 - Server Error
The service is unavailable.

Module IsapiModule 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler JWildCardHandler 
Error Code 0x00000000
```

Then after refreshing again, I get `Finally block` and if I keep refreshing the same behavior occurs over and over (Finally block then 503 error).

Comment: Not sure about the cause, but did you check all of the log files to see if it is an `Error` or an `Exception` (not the same thing)? Based on the behavior, it sounds like an `Error`. Despite what the documentation says, [you cannot trap those with cftry/cfcatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237283/coldfusion-not-catching-noclassdeffounderror/14243560#14243560).

Comment: @Leigh Nothing seems to show up in the exception log, but the explanation would make sense. However, what doesn't is that an `Error` is actually thrown from a cfindex tag. There's no reason calling on a Facade like cfindex should cause an unrecoverable error. If that's the case I would still consider that a bug IMO. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Plax - Did you check all of the logs, including /runtime/logs? I do not know for certain it *is* an `Error`, just that the behavior is similar. If it is, then yes - I agree that definitely should not happen. If you find out more, and/or can create a repro case, may want to file a bug report. Sorry I could not be of more help.