# Does cfcatch stop the processing?

Tags: coldfusion, try-catch, cfml

I have a ColdFusion query and am looping over the output.  I need a `try/catch` because there could be cases where the output of the query doesn't quite match the information I am processing.  It SHOULD match, but I am antsy about counting on it.  However, if there is a mismatch, no harm is done. I just want to skip that transaction and go on.  What I don't want is for ColdFusion to throw an error, stop the process, and upset my users.

In code like that below,  will the loop continue processing if it falls into the "catch" clause? There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation I found which addresses this question.

```
<cfoutput query = "xyz">
<cftry>
   do something with this line of query output ...
   <cfcatch type = "any">
   no action, just continue with the loop ...
   </cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty catch block will silently ignore the error and continue processing.  You should probably at least log the error though so you know if something is failing.

All that said, there are probably better ways to detect problems with the code than to try/catch it.  I don't understand what you mean when you say "the query [might not] quite match the information I am processing" so I can't provide any more specific of an example.

Comment: Thanks, Brad, that is exactly what I wanted to know.  And after I posted this I thought of a way to detect the error in this case prior to executing code that will fail.  So I think I am set.

Comment: A couple of my co-workers once did this intentionally.  They were using ColdFusion to populate one database from another, and used this technique to avoid primary key violations.

Comment: *RE: a way to detect the error* Good. It is better to prevent forseeable errors than catch them (when possible). Also, to clarify, cfcatch only handles *recoverable* exceptions. [Not all errors are considered recoverable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243560/104223). Serious/non-recoverable errors still bubble up to the OnError method or Site Wide Error Handler.